# Converting audio with sox in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sox

I have made sure that all that sox needs to function is installed, and I've also installed the [sox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox) package for node. Yet, this does not seem to work.

```
function encode(file, destination, quality) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(destination)

    let job = sox.transcode(file, destination, {
        sampleRate: 44100,
        format: 'mp3',
        bitRate: quality * 1024,
    })

    job.on('src', function(info) {
      console.log(info)
    });

    job.on('progress', (amountDone, amountTotal) => {
      console.log("progress", amountDone, amountTotal);
    });

    job.on('error', (err) => {
      reject('Could not transcode mp3.')
    })

    job.on('end', () => {
      resolve('mp3 transcoded.')
    })

    console.log(job)
  })
}
```

The `console.log` at the end logs:

```
Transcode {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { src: [Function],
     progress: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  inputFile: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\App\\Media\\media\\uploads\\audio/2016/269/1/0//10c746ef62374c6ab1f2ecfc36705618/original.mp3',
  outputFile: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\App\\Media\\media\\uploads\\audio/2016/269/1/0//10c746ef62374c6ab1f2ecfc36705618/128.mp3',
  options:
   { sampleRate: 44100,
     format: 'mp3',
     bitRate: 196608,
     channelCount: 2,
     compressionQuality: 5 } }
```

There are no errors, so I wonder if something here is failing silently. Identifying a file works just fine:

```
let original = (path + 'original.mp3')

sox.identify(original, function(err, info) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err)
   throw(err)
 }
 if (info.format !== 'mp3') {
   throw('File must be mp3!')
 }
 console.log(info) // {format: 'mp3', ..}
});
```

The above code works just fine. but `sox.transcode` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The example code](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-sox#transcode-an-audio-file) mentions a `job.start()` that (presumably) starts the transcoding job. I don't see that being called in your code.

Comment: Wow. How the hell did I miss that? That does make much more sense. I feel stupid now.